# Blazor - Dropdown issues selecting elements

Tags: binding, blazor, dropdown

I have Input Select component which is getting a list of Sites and it populates the dropdown fine however when I select an element, the List itself changes.

How can I prevent this (what am I doing wrong)?

Explanation of the issue:

1. The Dropdown loads perfectly fine and has the first element selected "Site A"
2. Clicking into the Dropdown (not selecting anything yet) shows Site A, Site B, Site C and Site D
3. Selecting Site B now makes my dropdown show: Site B, Site B, Site C and Site D

Where has Site A gone?

Selecting Site C shows :
Site C, Site B, Site C and Site D

So it looks like it is binding to the first element in the list, how do I stop that, I only want it to read from the list?

Console Output of Sites List when Site C Selected:

```
Site C
Site B
Site C
Site D
```

- 

```
<EditForm Model=Sites>
<InputSelect ValueExpression=@(()=>SelectedSite.Site)
Value=@SelectedSite.Site
ValueChanged=@((string value) => OnSiteValueChanged(value))>
    @foreach (var site in Sites)
    {
    <option  value=@site.Site>@site.Site</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

I am trying to binding the selection to another property called SelectedSite.
Everything works except for the lists contents.

**Additional Info:**

```
private void OnSiteValueChanged(string value)
        {
            SelectedSite.Site = value;
            foreach(var item in Sites)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Site);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
private void OnSiteValueChanged(string value)
{
    //this selects new site by value
    SelectedSite = Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Site == value);
}
```

Explanation:

In your original `OnSiteValueChanged()` method, you didn't select a new site, but you changed existing site from "Site A" to "Site B", resp "Site C".

Comment: Yes Sir, this does indeed fix the issue. Perfect!

Comment: This is a bad workaround that resorts to LINQ in order to set the "model" variable. Instead, you should have pointed out what is fundamentally  wrong with the code as a whole, how to use and when to use the EditForm component, etc.

Comment: I don't think this is fundamentally wrong. Given that InputSelect does not support binding selected value to complex type, this is the natural option. Feel free to downvote and provide better answer.

Comment: So you believe that the model provided to the `EditForm` component can be a list of strings (Sites). Is it the actual model object used, or perhaps its mere presence is to prevent compiler errors; after all, it does not serve any other purposes. As far as I know, a model should be a single object, usually a two-way data-binding applied to it. Here the "model" is actually a variable external to the EditForm component. As I said, this is a bad workaround, and expensive one as it resorts to LINQ in order to set the "model" variable.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use a loop to render Blazor content ( your `@foreach` ) you should use a `@key` directive on the rendered element(s) so that Blazor can track which elements it needs to add/remove or update.

```js
@foreach (var site in Sites)
{
 <option @key=site.Site value=@site.Site>@site.Site</option>
}
```

In this case, I would use `site.Site` as the `@key` as it appears to be a unique string, but you could just use `site` as the @key instead.

Comment: I do remember something about the @key now. If I use site.Site it does work but it gives me an error and furthermore, the list is still physically changed. ( I will post the error in the next comment). Note the sites are all unique and I have tried using just site which does NOT work. Am I doing something wrong with the OnSiteValueChanged or is it's binding causing some issue (I will post the code in the original question.

Comment: blazor.webassembly.js:1 
        
       crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: More than one sibling of element 'option' has the same key value, 'Site B'. Key values must be unique.
System.InvalidOperationException: More than one sibling of element 'option' has the same key value, 'Site B'. Key values must be unique.

Comment: Where does `Sites` come from? How is it populated? It shouldn't have duplicates presumably?

Comment: It comes from the API, which comes from a database and every "Site" which is the name and every ID which is the primary key is unique.